# Taking square photo in the app

Tags: ios, photo

I want to take square photo like the Instagram app since it does not make you crop the photo.  I do not want to put any filters however I want to take the photo as a square.  Is there away to do this in IOS6?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a new image context `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and within that draw you image you have taken with the camera in a `CGRect` using the `drawInRect:` method.